# Auto Start Android App at desired time and Auto Tap

Tags: android

I want to start an app in my android phone exactly at 3:00 PM and automatically tap on a specific area of that APP (a button which starts a video player). Can someone indicate if a solution already exist before I start making my own app to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to start at a given time, using an alarm clock. But if you want a point tapped at that time, I think that would be a security violation and it is unlikely you can do that. So you will need to write your own recording app.